# HTML5 video, position absolute z-index -1, hover Chrome bug

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a website that has a full screen video (height = window height) with text on top of it and a position fixed navigation underneath it.

With this combination whenever you scroll down the hover within my navigation will not register

I tried posting this on Jsfiddle but it was too buggy... So I put it somewhere else: [link](http://wiejeben.com/demo/video_bug.html)

```
video {position: absolute;z-index: -1;}
```

Causes the fixed block with the text 'Hover me' to not update when its hovered. I can only reproduce this bug in Google Chrome on Mac OS.

Demo video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b0odh9ciE8)

Comment: Just tried this test in IE 11 and Chrome, and I'm not sure what the issue is you are trying to describe. The hover effect blue/red works no matter what.

Comment: It only seems to effect Google Chrome browsers in Mac OS X (10.9.3)

Comment: I tested on Win 8.1, so yes it looks like it's some kind of bug related only to OSX+Chrome then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard answer to lots of chrome layering issues is often to make things a separate hardware accelerated layer.  Try adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

...to your video or navigation.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I'll keep this answer in mind for any other strange behaviour in the future.

Comment: Out of curiosity - which element needed the hack?  The navigation or the video?

Comment: I used it on the navigation. It also fixed some other stuttering in the layout that I was working on.